# CDN image update

Tags: bigcommerce

According to documentation,
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/other-handlebars-helpers

I use a CDN handlebar helper to add an image to my template:

```
<img src="{{cdn "webdav:img/about.jpg"}}">
```

After theme uploading, it was changed to:

```
<img src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-1tfospd5/content/img/about.jpg">
```

Okay, but I need to update the picture.
After uploading a NEW version of the picture to bigcommerce webdav, nothing changes, I still see the old one.
How can I update the picture on CDN?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait about 30 minutes until the CDN get the new image.

You can test if the new image is there by adding some querystring to your image :

https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-1tfospd5/content/img/about.jpg?test=test_new_image

You can try with :

```
<img src="{{cdn "webdav:img/about.jpg?new=logo"}}">
```

Comment: Does you pic exist in your BigCommerce folder : /content/img/about.jpg

Comment: Yes, the new one.

Comment: I can't see any image on your link : https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-1tfospd5/content/img/about.jpg can you provide the url of your website ?

Comment: Yes, I changed it
it is
https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-2tfospd6/content/img/about.jpg

Comment: Then you can force the load of your image by adding a querystring : https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-2tfospd6/content/img/about.jpg?test

Comment: I v just updated my answer, but i think you need to contact the support and ask why you still get the same old pic after 1 week.

Comment: If you don't want to wait for cdn, just change the image name in the code and upload a new file with that name.